# Bhatia—Davis inequality: first recorded occurrence?

Tags: probability, inequality, math-history

The Bhatia–Davis inequality states that, for any random variable $X$ such that $m \leq X \leq M$ a.s.,
$$
\operatorname{Var}[X] \leq (M-\mathbb{E}[X])(\mathbb{E}[X]-m)
$$
This is a strenghtening of [another inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances), attributed to Popovicius (1935). However, Bhatia and Davis only published their paper in 2000. **Was there no earlier recorded occurrence of this inequality?** It seems a little strange for it to have waited 65 years...

Comment: Isn't this trivial inequality used in a regular proof of Popoviciu's inequality? That's actually how I proved the latter, so easily that I didn't bother looking for (or reading) another proof. I have no access to Popoviciu's "Sur les équations algébriques ayant toutes leurs racines réelles" so I am not sure how he proved his inequality, but it's likely that the above was used in some proof much earlier than 2000.

Comment: This "trivial inequality" being strictly stronger than Popoviciu's, that'd be a bit strange?

Comment: (namely, Popovicu's inequality immediately follows from maximizing $(M-x)(x-m)$ over $x\in[m,M]$)

Comment: "being strictly stronger than Popoviciu's, that'd be a bit strange?" Not that strange, nor surprising, to me. Sharper inequalities are often hidden in proofs of weaker ones. By the way, I think I have found some interesting example, will post it in 20-30 minutes after a meeting.

Comment: The difference is: Popoviciu does *not* assume knowledge of the mean or the expectation. Bhatia and Davis do.

Comment: To @f10w's point, one proof of Chebyshev's inequality: for $X\ge 0$ and $f$ monotone nondecreasing, \begin{align*}P(X \ge a) &\le P(f(X) \ge f(a))\\ &= \int 1\{f(x) \ge f(a)\} dP(x)\\ &\le \int (f(x)/f(a)) 1 \{ f(x) \ge f(a)\} dP(x) \\ &\le \int (f(x)/f(a)) dP(x)\\ &= E(f(X))/f(a).\end{align*} The second inequality on the third line is actually a stronger version of Chebyshev

Answer (score 4):

As I said in a comment, it is likely that this inequality appeared much earlier than 1999-2000, possibly hidden in proofs of other inequalities like Popoviciu's. I myself obtained it when proving Popoviciu's inequality by *naturally* expanding $\mathbb{E}[(M-X)(X-m)]$. As a side note, in the following, the first identity yields Bhatia—Davis's inequality, and the second yields Popoviciu's:
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\operatorname{Var}[X] + \mathbb{E}[(M-X)(X-m)]} &\color{blue}{= (M-\mathbb{E}[X])(\mathbb{E}[X]-m)} \\
&\color{blue}{= \frac{(M-m)^2}{4} - \left(\mathbb{E}[X] - \frac{M+m}{2}\right)^2.}
\end{align}

After a quick search in the literature, I can confirm my above hypothesis. Indeed, Bhatia—Davis's inequality appeared (though not in the exact form) in a paper published by **H. E. Guterman in 1962** ("An Upper Bound for the Sample Standard Deviation"), highlighted in the red box below for your convenience:

[image]

[**Update for clarification:** Using the same notation in the question, the inequality in the red box reads $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X - \frac{M+m}{2}\right)^2\right] \le \frac{(M-m)^2}{4},$$
which is the inequality in question because
\begin{align}
\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} &= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (M+m)E[X] + \frac{(M+m)^2}{4} - \frac{(M-m)^2}{4}\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (M+m)E[X] + Mm \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X] - (M-\mathbb{E}[X])(\mathbb{E}[X] - m).
\end{align}
]

As you can see, it is hidden inside a proof of another inequality (which is also Popoviciu's if one looks more closely at the right-hand side in the red box, so my initial hypothesis is perfectly confirmed). Note that it is possible (or even likely) that this inequality was used even before 1962 by other researchers. If I can think of using $\mathbb{E}[(M-X)(X-m)]\ge 0$, so could our giants.

Comment: I must be missing something simple, but is the statement in the box actually the inequality in question? It seems to be, with the notation of the question, $$\mathbb{E}[(X-\frac{1}{2}(m+M))^2]$$ or am I misreading?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes it's the same inequality as in the question, that's the whole point of the answer.

Comment: I understand this is what the answers claims. What I'm saying is that the fact that $$\mathbb{E}[(X-\frac{1}{2}(m+M))^2]$$ and $$(M-\mathbb{E}[X])(\mathbb{E}[X]-m)$$ are equal is not entirely obvious to me -- is it? For a start, expanding one will have a $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, while the other will not.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry for not being clear enough. I have added some clarifications, please see the update.

Comment: @ClementC. I've just added even more clarifications. Hope that everything is clear enough now.

Comment: Thanks -- I see it now. Maybe I'm asking for too much, but I wouldn't really say that this is "an occurrence of the inequality" (instead of a result equivalent to it, if you know what to look for): relating it to the so-called Bhatia-Davis inequality to prove it takes 3 lines, while proving the Bhatia-Davis inequality directly also takes 3 lines.

Comment: @ClementC. That's your perspective, which I understand but strongly disagree with. For me they are **exactly** the same inequality. The number of "lines" is irrelevant here because that number highly depends on the level of the reader. For both of us what I presented could be just fine, but for an average student I could have added 5 more lines, by contrast maybe for a certain mathematician out there the results are immediate. 1/2

Comment: You may already know that many many classical inequalities that we are using today first appeared in different forms long time ago, yet regardless of the forms, we know (as we *should*) that they are the same. That said, if some day one of your PhD students comes to your office with a "new" concentration inequality that she wants to publish: $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X - \frac{M+m}{2}\right)^2\right] \le \frac{(M-m)^2}{4}$, you can safely say that "it's just the Bhatia–Davis inequality" (given that this attribution is accepted by the statistics community). That's my perspective. 2/2